# Getting the decimals in a double variable in a culture sensitive way

Tags: c#

Assume this double variable:

```
double d = 59.123;
```

How could I get the first 2 decimals in a string and in a culture sensitive way? That is:

```
string s = "12";
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can substract its integer part, multiply by 100, truncate decimal part and cast to string.

```
private string GetDecimalDigits(double d, int digitsCount)
{
    double substracted = d - Math.Floor(d);
    return Math.Round(substracted * Math.Pow(10, digitsCount)).ToString();
}

string result = GetDecimalDigits(59.123, 2);
```